# How to create complex type from stored procedure returning two tables

Tags: sql, entity-framework-4

How to create EF complex type from a stored procedure returning two tables and which runs dynamic SQL?

REF: [How to create a complex type from a stored procedure that uses exec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728148/how-to-create-a-complex-type-from-a-stored-procedure-that-uses-exec)

**UPDATE:**
I added following line in beginning of the procedure

```
SET FMTONLY OFF
```

now I am getting column information and able to create complex type for first result table only.

Comment: If your stored procedure returns more than one result set (more than  one `SELECT` in your stored procedure), you're out of luck for now. This is currently **not supported** by Entity Framework. It is  supported in EF v5 (.NET 4.5/VS 2012). [See this other SO question on the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086506/entity-framework-stored-procedure-with-multiple-resultsets)

Comment: @marc_s I'm not 100% sure but I imagine if this is supported in EF 5 it will also be supported in EF 4.4 (I'm not 100% sure as it could be implemented in the .Net component of EF not in the actual EF library in which case it wouldn't be included) but i think it would be worth a try with EF4.4 even if you cant use .net 4.5